# Field Update, leave unchanged if there's a value in the field

Tags: workflow, formula, field-update

I'm trying to create a field update on the Amount field in the Opportunity. If there is no Amount and that the Opportunity is Qualified, I want a default amount to be added. However if there is already something in there, I want to leave it unchanged.

Here's what I have for now:

IF(AND(Qualified_Opportunity__c =True,ISBLANK(Amount)),50000,"")

Thanks!
Segolene

Answer (score 0):

The workflow rule is only meant to return true or false depending on the formula, it's not meant to add a value. For that you would create a new field update. In the text box in the section Specify New Field Value you set your value for the field.

[image]

[image: field update]

Also your workflow rule can be simplified to only this:

```
AND(Qualified_Opportunity__c =True,ISBLANK(Amount))
```